# RewriteRule to an absolute path?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, apache2

I'm trying to make `RewriteRule` redirect to an absolute path on the server, outside of the current directory. This works when correctly implemented in PHP (i.e. no privilege issue), but with `.htaccess`, it doesn't:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ /var/www/files/html/$2
```

This is an example, though. Imagine this .htaccess file is at `/var/www/downloads/html` and redirects to the other location. Like I said, it's an example and doesn't have to make sense in this case.

This probably doesn't work because it redirects to `/var/www/files/html/var/www/downloads/html`, I think.

**Question:** How do I make RewriteRule point to a directory outside of the current one?

Update: The VirtualHost for this site is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/files/html
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You can only redirect within `DocumentRoot` so `/foo/bar/` in target will be redirected to `/var/www/foo/bar/`.

Comment: Can I change the DocumentRoot then?

Comment: That can be set from Apache config but cannot be changed in .htaccess

Comment: I updated my question, so you can see the `VirtualHost` for this site. When I change the `DocumentRoot` there to "/", it cannot access the `.htaccess` file anymore.

Comment: If you change `DocumentRoot` to `/` then .htaccess should also be placed as `/.htaccess`

Comment: I can't simply place the htaccess file in the topmost directory of the entire server. Is there another way?

Comment: That is true and `DocumentRoot` must never be set to `/` for security reasons as well. I was only answering your question on where htaccess should be placed.

Comment: Your rule should just be: `RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ /$1 [L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `DocumentRoot` to `/var/www` and place your .htaccess there. The rule could then look like

```
RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ /downloads/html/$1
```

But then, everything below `/var/www` will be publicly accessible. If this is not an option (e.g. security concerns), you must stick to your PHP solution.